# Advanced templating with jsp and sitemesh

Tags: java, jsp, sitemesh

Here's what i am trying to do:

I have a main template with header, menubar, body and footer. The body is replaced by the actual page called with the help of sitemesh like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <decorator:body />
</div>
```

Same for the title etc.

My problem is with the menubar: i would like to declare the content of the menubar in the actual page. The menus changes in every page, but i don't want to duplicate the layout of the menubar in every page.

My tools are JSP, Sitemesh and Spring MVC 3.

Is it possible? And if it is, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how i did it :

template.jsp :

```
<div class="menubar" >
   <decorator:getProperty property="page.navig"></decorator:getProperty>
</div>
```

actualpage.jsp :

```
<body>
   <content tag="navig">
      my menu \o/
   </content>
...
</body>
```

Note : without the 'page.' it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [page:applyDecorator tag](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/tags.html#page%3aapplyDecorator). You would have a dedicated decorator for the menu bar, responsible for the layout of the menubar, and the contents of the menubar would be in the body of the tag, in every page.

I have not used it, but this tag seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: oh, i saw this but didn't understand it. I'm going to test this now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a similar configuration of yours, I'm simply using a jsp include tag

```
<div class="mymenu">
    <jsp:include page="menu.jsp"/>
</div>
```